# URL for "article" (and other) entries of the .bib file?

Tags: bibtex, urls

My `.bib` file contains the following entry:

```
@Article{ LM11,
title = "Name of paper",
author = "Author A and Author B",
journal = "Arxiv",
year = "2011",
url = "http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/..."
```

The problem: when compiling, the title/author/journal shows ok, the URL does not appear at all. Same goes with similar entry types (e.g. book)

The bibliography is included in the following two lines:

```
\bibliography{bib_filename}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Comment: If you would use [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), then there is option `url` controlling whether URL should be shown in non-online entries, which is `true` by default, so it would work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `plain` bibliography style does not support the `url` field. Use e.g. the `plainurl` style instead (and load the `url` package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{ LM11,
title = "Name of paper",
author = "Author A and Author B",
journal = "Arxiv",
year = "2011",
url = "http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/..."
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{LM11}.

\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: +1 Thanks! Although I first wondered why it didnt work, I realized I had to run BibTex again, then build the PDF one more time :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and ultimately the following worked for me, seemingly also to be the simplest solution (in a hosted environment where I could not alter bib styles):

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

...

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{my_bib}
```

citing as:

```
\cite{Bacon:2000}
```

with a bib like:

```
@misc{Bacon:2000,
    author = {Crunchy Bacon},
    title = {Breakfast at Murphy's},
    month = {May},
    year = {2000},
    publisher = {Bacon Daily},
    note ={\url {http://www.dailybacon.com} (visited: 2014-11-09)}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is better to provide full examples

Comment: http://www.dailybacon.com (visited: 2024-02-15) leads me to a domain hosting company instead of bacon. And I really wanted to order that crunchy bacon for breakfast.