# URL with % won't display in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, urls, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL for “article” (and other) entries of the bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21633/url-for-article-and-other-entries-of-the-bib-file)
>   [URL of cited web site in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography)

I am trying to put a long URL into my bibliography. In the preamble I have this:

```
\urldef\calgary-outlook-a\url{http://www.calgary.ca/_layouts/cocis/DirectDownload.aspx?target=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.calgary.ca%2FCA%2Ffs%2FDocuments%2FCorporate-Economics%2FCalgary-and-Region-Socio-Economic-Outlook%2FCalgary-and-Region-Socio-Economic-Outlook-V1-Executive-Summary-2011-2021.pdf&noredirect=1&sf=1}
```

I've tried taking out the '-' from the urldef but it hasn't changed anything.

My cite looks like this:

```
\cite{website:calgary-outlook-volume1}
```

My bibliography style is plain. And my references.bib contains this:

```
@misc{website:calgary-outlook-volume1,
  author = "The City of Calgary",
  title = "Socio-Economic Outlook Volume 1 Executive Summary",
  month = "October",
  year = "2011",
  url = "\calgary-outlook-a"
```

}

The URL is not displayed! Even when I remove the quotes for url=

Comment: `plain.bst` doesn't know the `url` field. Use `note`

Comment: Also your url is actually `http://www.calgary.ca/CA/fs/Documents/Corporate-Economics/Calgary-and-Region-Socio-Economic-Outlook/Calgary-and-Region-Socio-Economic-Outlook-V1-Executive-Summary-2011-2021.pdf`

Comment: see: [URL of cited web site in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36255#36255)

Comment: Both of these solutions were helpful!! Thank you!